# Use iOS device for audio output from computer via USB

Tags: ios, windows, bluetooth

I just got new Bluetooth headphones, but my Windows 10 PC does not have bluetooth. Is there a way I can play all audio from my PC to my iPhone 7 (preferably via the USB charger), and then use my Bluetooth headphones connected to the iPhone?

Comment: Do you mean all audio? If so, I'd just spend $10 for a USB bluetooth dongle to plug into your PC. Then you can pair your headphones directly with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The closest thing I can think of, is opening Spotify on both devices. Control Spotify from your laptop and set the output device to your iPhone. Of course this only gives you Spotify Music.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Remote Desktop app, like chrome Remote Desktop. You might have to set your phone to not go to sleep. It can’t be done through usb, but you can still use the usb cord to keep your phone charged if it is battery you are worried about. It is not the best method, but is the easiest work around.